# Why the output total of ord got different value?

Tags: php, ascii

```
**Update**
Fixed : http://codepad.org/6pB0WUm5
by http://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze
```

I have two codes, basically is same, but why, I got different output?

```
function domain_value($domain)
{
   $split_domain = str_split($domain);
   $ord_count = NULL;
   foreach($split_domain as $key=>$value)
   {
      $ord_count += ord($value);
   }
   return $ord_count;
}
echo domain_value('abc');
```

and

```
echo ord('a')+ord('b')+ord('c');
```

**Output**

```
first output : 294
second output:  98
```

Comment: `+('c')` or `+ord('c')`?

Comment: sorry I was mistyped, the correct is +ord('c'). Edited, done.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://codepad.org/6pB0WUm5

Comment: Thanks deceze :) you helped me out.

Comment: @oknoorap, can you explain exactly how that _fixed_ your problem. The only difference between that code and what you have now is the PHP_EOL output. If the problem was indeed that you weren't using `ord` on every term, you should revert your question. Your current code does _not_ generate your current output.

Comment: I got same output by using PHP_EOL outside function, actually I just check about my functions. Then I realize my function was correct.

Answer (score 3):

And what happens when you use:

```
echo ord('a')+ord('b')+ord('c');
```

which is probably what you *intended* in that second one :-)

---

In other words, you appear to have left the `ord` of the final part of the expression.

In fact, the only way you would normally get `98` would be with:

```
echo ('a')+ord('b')+('c')
```

(with `ord` only on the second term) so you may want to check again. If, as you seem to now indicate, you're using `ord` on each term, that works fine for me.

Both of them return `294` from `97 + 98 + 99`, the ASCII values for `a`, `b` and `c`.

Comment: I want create new function to count domain ascii values, its just an example. :)